# How to Hide Element after number of clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I need to make an input tag hidden after it has been clicked at least twice. This is the JS/JQuery I have: (note I'm very new to the language)

```
var clickcounter = 0;
var clicker = document.getElementById("show-img-btn");

$("clicker").click(function(){
    clickcounter = clickcounter + 1;
});

if (clickcounter >= 2) {("clicker").style.display = "none;"};
```

I really don't know the solution to this problem. It could be something as simple as not having enough equal signs or something complex as the whole thing being wrong. Please correct me!

Comment: can you share your demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to keep the count variable safe from the rest of the scripts on the page.

You need to put all of your logic inside the click event handler, because the rest of the script only runs once.

You can simplify the check by using prefix incrementation of the count variable inside the conditional statement.

```js
(function(count){
    $("#show-img-btn").click(function(){
        if(++count === 2) this.style.display = 'none';
        return false; // returning false prevents form submission
    });
})(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="show-img-btn" value="click me!">
```

You can simplify it even more if there is nothing else that needs to be done on the second click like so.

```js
(function(count){
    $("#show-img-btn").click(function(){
        return ++count === 2 && (this.style.display = 'none'), false;
        // increment & check; hide on second click; always return false
    });
})(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="show-img-btn" value="click me!">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (clickcounter >= 2) {("clicker").style.display = "none;"};

if (clickcounter >= 2) {alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");};
```

Move this piece of code into the event handler. Otherwise, this is only ran once when your code is parsed, where `clickcounter = 0;`.

If you put it in `$("clicker").click(function(){`, it is run every time your event is triggered.

Comment: i didnt realize I left the alert if then, haha, that was just to test if it was working, just not displaying right or something

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out,

```
<div id="clickMe">Click me!</div>

var counter = 0;
var clickMe = document.getElementById("clickMe");

clickMe.addEventListener("click", function () {
    counter += 1;

    if (counter == 5)
        clickMe.style.display = "none";

    console.log(counter);
});
```

You should adapt it to fit you. As you can see I checked the counter each time the `div` was clicked unlike yours which was once only.

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/xcgh99ut/

**Edit 1**

Also your code has an error in it.

```
$("clicker").click(function(){

}
```

According to your code `clicker` is variable so it should be,

```
$(clicker).click(function() {

}
```

Or using jQuery,

```
$("#show-img-btn").click(function () {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working code:  https://jsfiddle.net/xj1noced/
You have to put your condition into the onclick event - so it's run everytime the user clicked the element.

html:

```
<div id="clicker">
     <div id="show-img-btn">Foo</div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var clickcounter = 0;
var clicker = document.getElementById("show-img-btn");

$("#clicker").click(function(){
     clickcounter = clickcounter + 1;
     if (clickcounter >= 2) {$("#clicker").css("display", "none")};
});
```